# How to append to a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello so I have this text filed named ***students.txt*** with names inside.

```
Buddy Mike Freshman 3.00
Allen Hood Sophmore 3.45
Dave Beck Freshman 3.00
Jose Sanford Sophmore 3.45
Juan Castro Freshman 3.00
```

I want to add the information the user entered to the existing file ***students*** and have it print out with the new contents.

```
def add_Student():
    myNames = []
    Name = input("Enter First and Last Name of Sudent: ")
    Status = input("Enter Status of Stdent: ")
    GPA = input("Enter Students GPA: ")
    newStudent = Student.Student(Name, Status, GPA )

    print("Student' Name: ",newStudent.getName())
    print("Student' Status: ",newStudent.getStatus())
    print("Student' GPA: ",newStudent.getGPA())
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 0):

To append data to a file you open it with the option "a":

```
with open("students.txt","a") as textfile:
    print(Name,Status,GPA,file=textfile)
```

Comment: oh thanks. What about adding spaces?

Comment: the result I get in the new one is ***Loki BlackFreshman3.00***

Comment: `print('{} {} {}'.format(Name, Status, GPA), file=textfile)`

Comment: Better than spaces, which lead to ambiguities, were tabs:

`print(Name,Status,GPA,file=textfile,sep="\t")`